# 簡単に数値を選択していれる方法はないでしょうか？

Tags: css

格子状のtableタグで作った表に数値を入れる物を作ったのですが、簡単に数値を選択していれる方法はないでしょうか？

selectタグでプルダウンメニューを入れたのですが、余計なcssが一杯当たっているせいか、サイズが大きくて崩れます。
下記を入れても変わりません。
appearance: none;

また、余計な余白や四角などが邪魔です。

typeにnumberと入れる方法もあるのですが、PCだと結局入力しないといけないですよね。

なにか良い方法はないでしょうか？

HTMLを追加します。

～

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="4"></td>
  <td><input type="text" value=""></td>←ここを閲覧者がクリックした時に1から9の選択肢が出てきて、選択するとその数値が入力される
</tr>
```

～

Comment: 表に入れる数値はプルダウンで選択できる（事前に候補となる数値が決まっている）ものなのですか？候補の種類が増えてくると、プルダウンから選択する時間が長くなりがちです。　余計な余白や四角は、なぜ表示されているのですか（消せないのですか）？　画面のスクリーンショット（まともな時と、くずれた時の両方）、HTMLのソース、といった具体的な状況が判る情報を質問に追加すると、適切な回答が期待できると思います。

Comment: 1から9までの数値だけです。また、自分でつけたcssではなくデフォルトで付いている、▼や枠やpaddingなどです。

Comment: @nicomesecond さん、具体的な状況があまり分かりません。具体的な HTML / CSS を共有して頂くことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: この HTML は何かから自動生成したものでしょうか？　色々と class が付いていますが、これは nicomesecond さん自身が付けられたものでしょうか？

Comment: クラス名で見にくかったでしょうから削除しておきました。

Comment: @nicomesecond さん、複雑さを気にしていたのではなく、「デフォルトで付いている〜」の件を気にしていました。まだ何が「デフォルト」なのか分からず、どういう状況なのか把握できていません。どういう手順で作成された HTML なのか追記して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyOQjm こちらにある程度再現しました。私の問いにあるソースは、こちらに変更前の物なので、少し違います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あまり詳しい状況が分かりませんが、余計な CSS が一杯あたっているために表示がおかしくなるのであれば、私だったらまずは CSS を整理するところから始めます。ブラウザに附属している検証ツールなど、CSS の整理をしやすくするツールを使うことも検討してください。

HTML 側についても、入力すべき数値の組み合わせが決まっていてしかも種類が少ないのであればプルダウンメニューが合っていそうですし、そうでないならテキストボックスにして後からバリデートすることになりそうです。

HTML / CSS に関する個別のより具体的な問題となると、実際に使われているコードや動作例のスクリーンショットなどが無いと回答しづらいです。

Comment: 自分でつけたcssではなくデフォルトで付いている、▼や枠やpaddingなどです。

Comment: 何（どんなアプリケーション？、どこのサイト？）のデフォールトなのですか？具体的な内容が何もない状態では、検討することも出来ないと思うのです。

Comment: テーブルのセルを押すとするっと1から9が出てきて選択した数値が入力されるようにしたいです。

Answer (score -4):

tdにidつけて

```
a=function(){document.getElementbyid(tdのid).innerhtml="number"}
```

で入れればいいと思います
selectのonchangeの時に関数いれれば良いと思います

```
<select onchange=a()></select>
```